# HTML tags are not working in echo tag in PHP

Tags: php, html

Here is my php code with html text box

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" value="<?php  
   $items=mysql_query("select * from order_detail_master where order_id = ".$no_of_orders['order_id']);
   echo "<table><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Qty</th></tr>";
     if($items){
         while($res_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($items)){

             $item_name = mysql_query("select item_name from item_master where item_id = ".$res_items['item_id']);
             while($item_name_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_name)){
                 $i_n = $item_name_rs['item_name'];
              }
             echo "<tr><td>".$i_n."</td><td>".$res_items['odm_quantity']."</td></tr>";
        }
}
```

echo "";

And my output look like
 [image]

Comment: You put table code as value of input... why?

Comment: do you really know what you are expecting?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you want to do with this code...

Comment: @noobCodeer : i just want to put table as a textbox value.

Comment: but when you do this, that is the result - table will not work. It will be only a TEXT nothing more. So decide - you want a table or want a table text?

Comment: so is there another way for what i want to do?

Comment: You can not have `table` in `text box`. What do you exactly want to do because right now it has no sense. `text box` is for `text` not for anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot
got your point..

Comment: @NehalPatel  if you try to use the table directly into textbox , it will not work as you expecting, what you can do is use a jquery editor : https://www.tinymce.com/  , connect this to your textbox and then it will start showing you the table in table format

Comment: Where is the `</table>` tag???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do either but I see no reason to have an html input type when it's not actually a form. If all you are doing is trying to query the database, I put this simple script together that might help guide you along the lines of what you are attempting to achieve. You can use * as a wild card in your mysql query line to help simplify things. Also, make sure $link matches your db_connect. I have not tested this but it should work fine.

```
<?php                              
$sql=mysqli_query($link, "select * FROM order_detail_master") or die(mysqli_error($link));
  ?>
    <tr>
      <th>Order ID</th>
      <th>Item ID</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>ODM Quantity</th>    
    </tr>
<?php      
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {     
  ?> 
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['order_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['item_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['item_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['odm_quantity'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php 
    } 
  ?>
```